# Self Modifying Code 8051

Tags: 8051

Let p0.0 be set to receive inputs and that it switches ON only once with an initial value 0f 0. Assuming that 8051 follows a regular Von Neumann Architecture , how can the number of cycles can be reduced?
The code is:

```
BACK :JNB P0.0,SKIP
DO_SOMETHING: CALL FIRST
SKIP: CALL SECOND                
SJMP BACK
```

I just know that `Self Modifying Code` is to be used but don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to it:

```
JNB P0.0,SKIP
DO_SOMETHING: CALL FIRST
SKIP: CALL SECOND                
NOP
```